# Vuetify dialog box doesn't appear when I press the associated button

Tags: html, user-interface, dialog, vuetify.js, confirm

I've created a button that should display a confirmation window once clicked to offer two options to the user. Now it creates a dialog that opens on its own before I click the associated button and it refuses to close when I hit the close button. Also, it closes when I click away but not it doesn't open when I click the starting button.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
<v-card raised class="mx-0 mb-3 pa-1"> <!-- My Uninstall -->>
  <v-card-text>
     <h3>Find PBNM Server</h3>
        <v-btn v-blur small color="primary lighten-2 black--text" class="mx-2" @click="chooseUninstall=true"><v-icon small left>fas fa-trash-alt</v-icon>Uninstall</v-btn>
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
<v-flex>
  <v-dialog v-if="chooseUninstall" v-model="chooseUninstall" scrollable max-width="95%">
     <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Uninstall Confirmation</v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions class="mb-3">
           <v-btn color="blue darken-1 white--text mx-3" @click="saveUninstall">Confirm Uninstall</v-btn>
           <v-spacer />
           <v-btn color="success darken-1 white--text mx-3" @click="chooseUninstall = false">Cancel</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
     </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</v-flex>
</template>

<script>
import api from '@/data/api';
import { findServer, testURL, getServerURL } from '@/util/findServer';
import eventBus from '@/util/eventBus';
import misc from '@/util/misc';
import queries from '@/data/queries';
import requests from '@/data/requests';
import ini from '@/util/ini';
import { SET_SERVERCFG } from '@/data/storeMutations';
import SettingsModule from '@/util/Settings';
import SpecialCombo from '@/components/users/lib/SpecialCombo';

const ICON_UNKNOWN = 'fas fa-question';
const ICON_INPROGRESS = 'fas fa-spinner fa-pulse';
const ICON_SUCCESS = 'fas fa-check';
const ICON_FAIL = 'fas fa-times';

export default {
  components: { SpecialCombo },
  data: () => ({

    dialog: false,

    
    showAvatarPicker: false,
    newAvatar: undefined, // completed by onAvatarChoice after a change

    showAuditLog: false,
    showPasswordPicker: false,

    showUninstall: false,
    

    editingDisplayName: false,
    newDisplayName: '',

    editingUserName: false,
    newUserName: '',
    

    inactivityTimeout: 12,
    passwordExpiry: 34,
    changePasswordWarning: 0,
    serverHost: '',
    serverIcon: ICON_UNKNOWN,
    themeChoices: [
      'default',
      'alternative',
      'high contrast'
    ],
    languages: [
      'English',
      'Français'
    ],
    showLang: false,
    langChoice: 'English',
    locale: 'en',
    themeModes: [ ],    // translated, like this.$i18n.t('themeModes')
    themeModeIndex: 0,  // index in themeModes array
    themeModeText: '',  // translated themeMode, like langChoice vs locale
    themeMode: SettingsModule.Defaults.themeMode,
    themeChoice: SettingsModule.Defaults.themeChoice,
    rememberPosition: SettingsModule.Defaults.rememberPosition,
    rememberMaximized: SettingsModule.Defaults.rememberMaximized,
    messageOfTheDay: '',
    noPasswordExpiry: true,
    noInactivityTimeout: true,
    minuteComboItems: [ ],
    dayComboItems: [ ],
    warningComboItems: [ ]
  }),
  computed: {
    isConnected () {
      return this.$store.getters.getConnected;
    },
    hasUser() {
      return queries.isAuthenticated()
    },
    isElectron() {
      return window.isElectron;
    },
    allowNoInactivityTimeout() {
      return this.serverCfg.allowNoInactivityTimeout || false;
    },
    allowNoPasswordExpiry() {
      return this.serverCfg.allowNoPasswordExpiry || false;
    },
    maxInactivityTimeout() {
      return this.serverCfg.maxInactivityTimeout || 1440;
    },
    maxPasswordExpiry() {
      return this.serverCfg.maxPasswordExpiry || 365;
    },
    maxPasswordExpiryWarning() {
      return this.maxPasswordExpiry;
    },
    allowManage() {
      return false;
    },
    isWebApp () {
      return window.isWebApp;
    },
    isDevelopment() {
      return (NODE_ENV === 'development');
    },
    showToolbarLogo () {
      return this.windowSize.x >= 720;
    },
    serverCfgChanged() {
      let inactivityTimeoutVal = parseInt(this.inactivityTimeout);
      let passwordExpiryVal = parseInt(this.passwordExpiry);
      let passwordWarningVal = parseInt(this.changePasswordWarning);
      let serverMOTD = this.serverCfg.messageOfTheDay || '';
      return (inactivityTimeoutVal !== this.serverCfg.inactivityTimeout)
          || (passwordExpiryVal !== this.serverCfg.passwordExpiry)
          || (passwordWarningVal !== this.serverCfg.changePasswordWarning)
          || (this.messageOfTheDay !== serverMOTD);
    },
    serverCfg() {
      return this.$store.getters.getServerCfg;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeMyDialog(){
      this.dialog = false;
    },
    openDialog() {
      this.dialog = true;
    },
    chooseUninstall(){
      this.showUninstall=true;
    },
    saveUninstall() {
      api.apiPost('/uninstall', { })
      .then((result) => { 
        eventBus.emit('snack', {text: 'Uninstall successful.', color: 'success'});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        requests.handleError(err);
      });
    },
    onThemeMode (mode) {
      this.themeMode = mode;
      this.themeModeIndex = (mode === 'dark') ? 1 : 0;
      this.themeModeText = this.themeModes[this.themeModeIndex];
    },
    onUpdateLang () {
      // This is invoke by the UI form when the v-select choice is changed
      this.locale = (this.langChoice === 'Français') ? 'fr' : 'en';
      this.$i18n.locale = this.locale;
      eventBus.emit('locale', this.locale);
    },
    onUpdateThemeMode () {
      // this.settings.themeMode is always english
      // this.themeMode is always english
      // this.themeModeText is always localized
      // this.themeModes is always localized (computed property)
      // light always comes first, then dark.
      this.themeModeIndex = (this.themeModeText == this.themeModes[1]) ? 1 : 0;
      this.themeMode = this.themeModeIndex === 1 ? 'dark' : 'light';
      this.doSave();
      eventBus.emit('themeMode', this.themeMode);
    },
    protocolColor(proto) {
      return proto ==='https' ? 'success--text' : 'error--text'; // return a class
    },
    onNewInactivityTimeout(val) {
      this.inactivityTimeout = val;
    },
    onNewPasswordExpiry(val) {
      this.passwordExpiry = val;
    },
    onNewChangePasswordWarning(val) {
      this.changePasswordWarning = val;
    },
    doSave (onServer) {
      // Persist the settings and make these settings available to the whole app now.
      this.settings.locale = (this.locale === 'fr') ? 'fr' : 'en';
      this.settings.themeMode = this.themeMode;
      SettingsModule.SettingsSave(this.settings);

      if (onServer && this.hasUser && this.serverCfgChanged) {
        let inactivityTimeoutVal = parseInt(this.inactivityTimeout);
        let passwordExpiryVal = parseInt(this.passwordExpiry);
        let passwordWarningVal = parseInt(this.changePasswordWarning);
        let newServerCfg = Object.assign({}, this.serverCfg, {
              inactivityTimeout: inactivityTimeoutVal,
              passwordExpiry: passwordExpiryVal,
              changePasswordWarning: passwordWarningVal,
              messageOfTheDay: this.messageOfTheDay
            });
        api.apiPut('/config', newServerCfg)
        .then((configResult) => {
          // TODO: There's no server message on config change yet so update the store manually here.
          this.$store.dispatch(SET_SERVERCFG, newServerCfg);

          // Notify user
          eventBus.emit('snack', {text: `Server configuration updated.`, color: "success"});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          requests.handleError(err);
        });
      }
    },
    onInputServer() {
      this.serverIcon = ICON_UNKNOWN;
    },
    reformatURL(url, port) {
      let result = url.includes('://') ? url : 'https://'+url;
      return (port && !isNaN(port)) ? result + ':' + port : result;
    },
    onLocale(locale) {
      this.locale = locale;
      this.langChoice = (this.locale === 'fr') ? 'Français' : 'English';
      // need to update the language-specific themeModes array as well as the index and mode itself
      this.themeModeIndex = (this.themeModeText == this.themeModes[1]) ? 1 : 0; // first find the old index
      this.themeModes = JSON.parse(this.$i18n.t('themeModes'));                 // next update modes for the language
      this.themeMode = (this.themeModeIndex === 1) ? 'dark' : 'light';
      this.themeModeText = this.themeModes[this.themeModeIndex];  // themeModes updates on locale change
      SettingsModule.SettingsUpdate({locale: this.locale, themeMode: this.themeMode});
      this.doSave();
    },
    clear () {
      this.locale = SettingsModule.Defaults.locale;
      this.langChoice = (this.locale === 'fr') ? 'Français' : 'English';
      this.settings.themeChoice = SettingsModule.Defaults.themeChoice;
      this.settings.themeMode = SettingsModule.Defaults.themeMode;
      this.themeMode = this.settings.themeMode;
      this.themeModeIndex = (this.themeMode === 'dark') ? 1 : 0;
      this.themeModes = JSON.parse(this.$i18n.t('themeModes'));
      this.themeModeText = this.themeModes[this.themeModeIndex];
      this.settings.rememberPosition = SettingsModule.Defaults.rememberPosition;
      this.settings.rememberMaximized = SettingsModule.Defaults.rememberMaximized;

      this.$i18n.locale = this.locale;
      this.doSave(); // does the save

      eventBus.emit('locale', this.locale);
      eventBus.emit('themeMode', this.themeMode);
    },
    async doTestServer () {
      if (!(this.serverHost)) return;
      let result = false;
      this.serverIcon = ICON_INPROGRESS;
      try {
        this.serverHost = this.reformatURL(this.serverHost);
        let pbnmCfg = misc.initCfg(true)
        result = await testURL(pbnmCfg, this.serverHost, false);
      } catch {
        result = false;
      }
      this.serverIcon = result ? ICON_SUCCESS : ICON_FAIL;
    },
    async doAutodetectServer () {
      this.serverIcon = ICON_INPROGRESS;
      let pbnmCfg = misc.initCfg(true)
      let result = await findServer(pbnmCfg, true);
      if (result) {
        this.serverHost = result;
        this.serverIcon = ICON_SUCCESS;
      } else {
        this.serverIcon = ICON_FAIL;
      }
      console.log(`Auto-detect server returns`, result);
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.locale = this.$i18n.locale;
    this.serverHost = getServerURL() || this.serverHost;
    this.minuteComboItems = misc.minuteComboItems.slice();
    this.dayComboItems = misc.dayComboItems.slice();
    this.warningComboItems = misc.warningComboItems.slice();
    this.settings = SettingsModule.SettingsCopy(this.$root.appSettings);
    let cfg = this.$store.getters.getServerCfg;
    this.inactivityTimeout = cfg.inactivityTimeout;
    this.passwordExpiry = cfg.passwordExpiry;
    this.changePasswordWarning = cfg.changePasswordWarning;
    this.messageOfTheDay = cfg.messageOfTheDay;
  },
  mounted() {
    // Normal.vue needs this for policies, phones, applications, subnets, users and roles
    this.$emit('subcomponent', this);
    eventBus.hook('locale', this.onLocale);
    eventBus.hook('themeMode', this.onThemeMode);
    let pbnmCfg = misc.initCfg(true);
    this.showLang = misc.boolOption(pbnmCfg, 'multilingual', false);
    this.locale = this.$i18n.locale;
    this.langChoice = (this.locale === 'fr') ? 'Français' : 'English';
    this.themeModes = JSON.parse(this.$i18n.t('themeModes'));                 // next update modes for the language
    this.themeMode = this.settings.themeMode;
    this.themeModeIndex = (this.themeMode === 'dark') ? 1 : 0;
    this.themeModeText = this.themeModes[this.themeModeIndex];  // themeModes updates on locale change
    if (this.locale !== 'fr') this.locale = 'en';    // force it to be one of the two
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    eventBus.unhook('themeMode', this.onThemeMode);
    eventBus.unhook('locale', this.onLocale);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: add script part of your code too, so we can understand the actual problem

Comment: @NileshMishra I updated it with the script!

Comment: chooseUninstall variable is not present in data,maybe that's the problem

Comment: @NileshMishra YES! That's got it, thank you! :D